# Can non-residents enter libraries in Tel Aviv?

Tags: paperwork, legal, israel, tel-aviv, science

If I am a US citizen in Tel Aviv, would I be able to sit in the Shaar Zion library and do work? The [library website](https://www.tel-aviv.gov.il/en/Live/Education/Pages/Public-Libraries.aspx) says, "Tel Aviv-Yafo residents can utilize the city’s libraries without charge upon presentation of ID card and resident card". What about non-residents—are they allowed in with some sort of registration, or would I not be allowed in at all?

Comment: [This site](https://www5.tel-aviv.gov.il/TlvForms/RegistrationLibrary/) (in Hebrew, which I can only read via Google Translate) seems to say that non-residents can pay a fee to borrow books.  However, it's not clear to me if that fee is also required to simply enter the library.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: It absolutely isn't. I've entered... maybe 8 or 10 municipal libraries in Israel and nobody ever asked me to prove residence in order to get in. They might check your bag for bombs though :-P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can enter the building if that's what you're asking. The WiFi is free, but other services require subscription. Here's [the price list](https://www.tel-aviv.gov.il/Visitors/ArtCulture/Documents/%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%99%20%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA.pdf) (ILS). For books only it's 350ILS (for Shaar Zion, it is more expensive than others), for books and digital media it's 400ILS (all the same).

To register and set up a subscription you'll need to get there and do it in person (residents don't need to pay and can register online).

Comment: I'm quite sure free entry allows you to take a book and read it on premise. Most libraries allow this, not sure about this specific one

Comment: @ugoren It's been a while since I used a library, but IIRC there are no large "reading halls" there, so I doubt it. You'll have to check the book out for any reasonable length of work. But worth a try, I guess.

Comment: Indeed no reading halls, but libraries do have some chairs and desks. No problem spending a few hours there (as long as you keep quiet of course)

Comment: @ugoren are you saying that based on your experience in that particular library?

Comment: From personal experience gained 5 minutes ago. The library, not the one OP asks about but much smaller, has some tables and chairs.

Answer (score 2):

#### tl;dr: "without charge" regards book loans only.

The phrase

> Tel Aviv-Yafo residents can utilize the city’s libraries without charge upon presentation of ID card and resident card

means residents can *check out* books from city libraries without charge. Libraries in Israel generally do not check for residence or citizenship status for visiting and working in the library (if they have a work area, that is). In fact, it is culturally inconceivable to restrict library access by place-of-residence - so much so that the municipality did not consider your interpretation of their notice and thus failed to clarify the wording.